# Synchronizing cookies between Windows Chrome and Android Chrome?

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, windows

Is there an app/hack which automatically synchronizes cookies between Windows Chrome and Android Chrome? That way there would be no need to login to websites twice.

History/saved passwords are already shared so perhaps someone went one step further.

Comment: Apparently [Google Browser Sync is supposed to do this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Browser_Sync). Does anyone else use Chrome on all their devices and have cookies synced?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. History/saved passwords/bookmarks are synced though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2017 Chrome doesn't support automatic synchronization of cookies between mobile and desktop versions, except for Google's own apps. I'm not sure why it's not mentioned anywhere, but it simply doesn't work.

Perhaps future versions of Android/Chrome will solve the issue.